# Can't get updates on 14.04

Tags: updates

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: As already stated [ it might be a duplicate ] please always add some details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use sudo at start of your command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```